# How deep a container do I need for my Kangaroo Paw?

Tags: houseplants, flowers, container-gardening

I have a Kangaroo Paw var. "Amber Velvet" (an *[Anizoganthos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anigozanthos)* hybrid), that I will have to grow as a container plant because it's not hardy in my climate (USDA Zone 8a) and must be brought indoors in the winter.

Some Internet research tells me that it will spread horizontally rapidly, so the container should be fairly wide. Also that it likes sandy, well drained soils. What I haven't been able to find out is how deep that soil should be when they're grown as a container plant.

Since it will have to be moved a couple of times a year (at least), and also because it'll be taking up space in my house for much of the time, I'd like to minimize the size of the container it's in, while still giving the plant enough room to thrive.

How deep a container should it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about this one spreading horizontally fast, so even though it's not necessary, you can go very wide with your pot. But to answer the question, you can get away with 1' deep (about 7.5 gallons per square foot) pots/planters.

This is pretty deep, but necessary because this is a deep-rooted plant and shouldn't get too root-bound. Also, use very light, gritty, well-drained soil or mix, to simulate natural habitat. This will automatically lighten your pot (for moving in and out of the house). Of course, you will know to choose a lightweight container to begin with.

Depending on your house entrance and container choice, you can install castors on the base of the container to make it easier to move. I don't think it will be a big deal.